# How to save free form user input in Alexa Skill Fact

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create a skill fact that sends a ticket to an office through alexa. I want the user to input their email, name, and issue in the email. The problem is that I am not sure how to get free form text and save it in either an intent slot or in index.js

I've looked into AMAZON.LITERAL but it is no longer functional. I also looked at AMAZON.searchQuery but that doesn't seem to be what I want since that queries from a database. And I would prefer not to create a custom intent with thousands of possible emails from the business.

Ideally I want the code to look something like this:

```
const sendEmailIntentHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'sendEmail';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const speechText = "what is your email";
        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt()
            .getResponse();
            //somewhere here store the response as a session variable
    }
};
```

I've looked into getResponse() and I don't think it does what I think it does, which is stores the response from the user. Is it possible to store the user input on the index.js side? Or is it only possible through slots?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to [request the customer contact information permission](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-customer-contact-information-for-use-in-your-skill.html) and just add a custom slot for your intent with a list of possible ticket issues.

This way when your users enable the skill they will have to consent to their information sharing and you'll already have that on hand when they make the request.

Unfortunately it's no longer possible to obtain free form input from users.